# Data unable to save into database IOS CoreData Swiftui Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

Hi I have this function that will save data to the entity

```
 func addOrder(room: Room, userID: String, orderDetail: OrderDetail) {
        let order = Order(context: container.viewContext)
        
        order.id = UUID()
        order.name = orderDetail.name
        order.ownerID = room.ownerID
        order.tenant_id = userID
        order.tenant_ic = orderDetail.identityCard
        order.phoneNum = orderDetail.mobileNumber
        order.move_in_date = DateFormatter().string(from: orderDetail.moveInDate)
        order.created_at = Date()
        order.updated_at = Date()
        order.room_id = room.id!.uuidString
        
        print(order)
        
        save(context: container.viewContext)
    }
```

however, at the print(order) line
this is the output I get

```
<Order: 0x600000955450> (entity: Order; id: 0x600002aaec60 x-coredata:///Order/tD85A0123-DDC2-48FB-8414-F4F52913C8258; data: {
    "created_at" = "2022-09-11 13:26:18 +0000";
    id = "458AF674-BE42-4266-8D3C-6BEA6B78FCAF";
    "move_in_date" = "";
    name = "";
    ownerID = "A0051C62-4C91-4AF3-B42C-79FFD2B7275D";
    phoneNum = "";
    "room_id" = "FBAABEF2-7A58-4BE7-A01A-AA6DECB76767";
    "tenant_ic" = "";
    "tenant_id" = "F7176157-A432-4F0B-9767-BFC09D5AA756";
    "updated_at" = "2022-09-11 13:26:18 +0000";
})
```

why the room_id, tenant_ic.... the keys are double quoted?
and I notice those double quoted data, none of them get saved into database
why is it so?

Data Model:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension Order {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Order> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Order>(entityName: "Order")
    }

    @NSManaged public var created_at: Date?
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var move_in_date: String?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var ownerID: String?
    @NSManaged public var phoneNum: String?
    @NSManaged public var room_id: String?
    @NSManaged public var tenant_ic: String?
    @NSManaged public var tenant_id: String?
    @NSManaged public var updated_at: Date?

}

extension Order : Identifiable {

}
```

Comment: What does your data model look like? I noticed that the ones in quotes have underscores (`_`) in them.

Comment: @ProgrammerG oh! That might be the thing, I try remove them and try again. The data model I updated in my post already

Comment: @ProgrammerG Seems like that is what caused the issue! Thankyou! You saved my day, do you want to answer the question so that I can mark that as best answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the only ones double quoted had underscores (`_`) in them.

Why don’t you try using [camelCase](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) case instead?